# Download location for mobicents mgcp stack?

Tags: mobicents

Where can I download the mobicent mgcp stack from? The URL http://www.mobicents.org/mms/mms-mgcp-downloads.html takes me to the download page but ultimately it points to mobicent diameter which is not I am looking for.

Would appreciate receiving an exact location to the binary to download.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The stack client side code is at https://github.com/Mobicents/mediaserver/tree/master/client/mgcp. Libraries are at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mobicents.media.client/mgcp-driver

The stack server side code is at https://github.com/Mobicents/mediaserver/tree/master/controls/mgcp. Libraries are at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mobicents.media.controls/mgcp/

Comment: what do you want to use the MGCP for ?